# Catalan numbers, Pochhammer symbols, Stirling numbers of the second kind, and sums of aliquot parts

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, integer-sequences, divisors-multiples

For integers $N\geq 1$ we define $$s(N)=\sigma(N)-N$$ the aliquot sum function, where $\sigma(N)=\sum_{1\leq d|N}d$ is the sum of divisors function.

Here  $(x)_n$ is the Pochhammer symbol and ${a\brace b}$ the Stirling numbers of the second kind (the encyclopedia Wolfram MathWorld has the articles [*Pochhammer Symbol*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) and [*Stirling Number of the Second Kind*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html) respectively).

Inspired in [1] I add this conjecture. And below I add another conjecture, but the question is just about the next.

**Conjecture 1.** *The only solution in positive integers* $(n,m)$ *for the equation*
$$s\left({2n\brace n}\right)=(m)_m\tag{1}$$
*is the trivial solution* $(2,1)$.

> **Question.** What work can be done about the veracity of this Conjecture 1?
> Does the equation $(1)$ have a finite number of solutions $(n,m)$? **Many thanks.**

Thus I am asking if it is possible to prove or refute the Conjecture 1.

### References:

[1] Douglas E. Iannucci and Florian Luca, *Catalan numbers, factorials, and sums of aliquot parts*, The Fibonacci Quarterly, Volume 45, Number 4 (November 2007).

---

As appendix we add the following conjecture inspired in [1], after I've read some excerpts I condlude that a great part of the work in [1] can be useful to study the following conjecture. Thus I need to study more the article to solve Conjecture 2.

**Conjecture 2.** *Let* $C_n=\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{n+1}$ *be the Catalan numbers,* $(x)_n$ *the Pochhammer symbols and* ${a\brace b}$ *the Stirling numbers of the second kind.*

A) *The only solutions in positive integers* $(n,m)$ *for the equation*
$$\sigma\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}\right)-\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{n+1}=(m)_m$$
*are the trivial solutions* $(2,1)$ *and* $(3,1)$.

B) *The only solutions in positive integers* $(n,m)$ *for the equation*
$$\sigma\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}\right)-\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{n+1}={2m\brace m}$$
*are the trivial solutions* $(2,1)$ *and* $(3,1)$.

Comment: So, the basic idea here is, take a few number-theoretical functions, throw them together in an entirely unmotivated way, and ask some question about them without any sign of having done any work to resolve the problem. I'm not sure that this is the road to progress in mathematics.

Comment: I cannot discuss professional aspects of mathematics with you, because I am an amateur. I think that the motivation is that these conjectures are similar than propositions showed in [1], and I am asking about Conjecture 1, because I hope to continue my study of the article [1]. I know how humble my contributions are, thus I don't call the contributions of my posts as progress. I call it effort and sacrifice @GerryMyerson

Comment: There's a link to the Iannucci-Luca paper at https://www.fq.math.ca/45-4.html, the MathWorld articles are at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html